# Don't see what's wrong with my javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a syntax error saying there is an unexpected ")" -- just don't see it - anyone?

```
<script>
$(".signin_link_other").click(function() {
    $('#login_dropdown').clone().appendTo($(this)).toggle();
)};

$(".signup_link_other").click(function() {
    $('#signup_dropdown').clone().appendTo($(this)).toggle();
)};
</script>
```

Comment: Change both `)};` to `});`.

Comment: You should use an editor that matches brackets, so you will see problems like this easily.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".signin_link_other").click(function() {
    $('#login_dropdown').clone().appendTo($(this)).toggle();
)};
```

->

```
$(".signin_link_other").click(function() {
    $('#login_dropdown').clone().appendTo($(this)).toggle();
});
```

Change `)};` to `});`

2nd one is similar.

Comment: It will be helpful to describe what you changed.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to this:

```
<script>
$(".signin_link_other").click(function() {
$('#login_dropdown').clone().appendTo($(this)).toggle();
});

$(".signup_link_other").click(function() {
$('#signup_dropdown').clone().appendTo($(this)).toggle();
});
</script>
```

All you had to do was change all of the `)};` to `});`